# Dynamic Order By using parent value and mixed column types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table named `Report`, the columns in `Report` as followed:

```
Id(char)     
Name(char)     
ParentId(char)     
Sequence(int)     
SortBy(char)
```

The table has some hierarchies. Each row's `ParentId` is another row's `Id`(the top hierarchy's `ParentId` is NULL). The `SortBy` filed is either `"Name"` or `"Sequence"`.

Now I want get a `SELECT * FROM Report`. The result I want to get is group by the `ParentId`, but in each group, it is ordered by `SortBy`, where the `SortBy`'s value is in the row Id = this group 's ParentId.

More specifically, if a group's `ParentId` is `"animal"`, the `SortBy` of the row that Id is `"animal"` is `"Name"`, I want this group is sorted by `"Name"`.

Is anyone can help? Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: the order by cluse can have a case statement in it - this sounds ugly however.

Comment: Some data example would be helpful

Comment: Do you want the content of the `SortBy` field to relate to the table columns `name` / `sequence` and thus influence the sort order in your SQL?

Comment: Are you saying that "SortBy" contains the *name* of the column you want to sort by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` in the order by to dynamically sort by the parent.  The only tricky issue with your case is that the columns you can sort by are different data types.  In that case you have to cast them to a common data type.

### Query

The query is simple.  Left join to the parent and use the parent to determine the second sort parameter in the case.  The first sort parameter is the `parentId` -- that keeps the children grouped together.

There are two ways to handle `Sequence`.  You can either cast it as an varachar and use pad, or add a third sort parameter.  There was no change in the execution plan, but I expect separating the order by columns by type is better if there is an **index** for the `Sequence` column

```
SELECT Child.*
FROM #Report [Child]
LEFT JOIN #Report [Parent] ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId
ORDER BY 
    Child.ParentId,
    CASE Parent.SortBy WHEN 'Name' THEN Child.Name END,
    Sequence -- sort by sequence if no column is matched
```

*Alternative `ORDER BY`*

```
ORDER BY 
    Child.ParentId,
    CASE Parent.SortBy
        WHEN 'Name' THEN Child.Name
        ELSE RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(Child.Sequence AS VARCHAR), 10)
    END
```

### Setup Code

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.objects WHERE NAME LIKE '#Report%') 
    DROP TABLE #Report;

CREATE TABLE #Report
(
    Id CHAR(20),     
    Name CHAR(20),
    ParentId CHAR(20),
    Sequence INT,
    SortBy CHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO #Report VALUES
('a', 'zName', 'f', 2, ''),
('b', 'bName', 'f', 3, ''),
('c', 'cName', 'g', 7, ''),
('d', 'dName', 'g', 5, ''),
('e', 'eName', 'g', 6, ''),
('f', 'fName', '', 9, 'Name'),
('g', 'gName', '', 8, 'Sequence');
```

### Output

```
Id  Name    ParentId    Sequence    SortBy
f   fName               9           Name                
g   gName               8           Sequence            
b   bName    f          3                       
a   zName    f          2                       
d   dName    g          5                       
e   eName    g          6                       
c   cName    g          17
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select r.*
from Report r
    left join Report p on p.ID = r.ParentID
order by r.ParentID,
    case p.SortBy
        when 'Sequence' then right('0000000000' + cast(r.Sequence as varchar(10)), 10)
        else r.Name
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative option using `RANK OVER` and `UNION`

```
SELECT Child.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Child.ParentID ORDER BY Child.Sequence) AS Ranked
FROM Report Child
LEFT JOIN Report Parent  ON Parent.ID = Child.ParentID
WHERE Parent.SortBy = 'Sequence'
ORDER BY Child.ParentID, Ranked
SELECT Child.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Child.ParentID ORDER BY Child.Name) AS Ranked
FROM Report Child
LEFT JOIN Report Parent  ON Parent.ID = Child.ParentID
WHERE Parent.SortBy = 'Name'
ORDER BY Child.ParentID, Ranked
```